# Android Studio Issue on Mac

Tags: android, sdk, ide, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am using new android studio .when i download and install it there was no issue. But now when i try to create a new project it's show this error

```
   Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. 
   Please ensure you are using SDK version 22 or later.
```

As you know the latest SDK version is already bundled with android studio .I tried re-installing android studio still that error exist.

But it works fine while importing a project or opening an old project. I am facing this only during while trying to create a new project

Somebody help me to resolve this

**Note** : Im using Mac 10.6.8

EDIT : Screen Shot

[image]

I check my SDK manger which is bundled with android studio It's showing i'm using latest version

Answer (score 2):

I've occurred this problem, what I did is.

1. On Main Menu, Click, Configure
2. Click Project Defaults
3. Click Project Structure
4. In Platform Settings > SDK, Choose the Build Target. Restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment (Low reputation) but have you tried checking the android sdk manager? See if anything is outdated or missing in `tools`

Then follow the answer above me, or check `module settings > Dependencies > Module SDK` and verify that it's android 4.2.2